# How to override moment.js locale formatting in version 2.10.x, worked in 2.8.x

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I was using "internal" moment.js API to override formatting of current locale - namely disabling arabic number symbols. So instead of `١١ أيلول سبتمبر ٢٠١٥ ١٩:٥٣` I would have `11 سبتمبر/ أيلول 2015 19:53`

But after upgrading to v 2.10.x, this internal hack broke and I cannot find how to hook into moment and override this

```
moment.locale("ar");
moment._locale.postformat = function (input) { return input; };
document.write(moment().format("LLL"));
```

v2.8.x http://jsbin.com/faziyu/3/edit?html,js,console,output

v2.10.x http://jsbin.com/faziyu/4/edit?html,js,console,output

"TypeError: Cannot set property 'postformat' of undefined

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old but coming across in in my project. Just use `moment()._locale` with brackets to access the internal _locale property.

v2.18.1: http://jsbin.com/comosidida/embed

```
moment.locale("ar");
moment()._locale.postformat = function (string) { return string; }; // jshint ignore:line
document.write(moment().format("LLL"));
```

**Note**: There is a little difference in print between both version coming from moment.js.

v2.8:6 سبتمبر/ أيلول 2017 10:59

v2.18.1: 6 أيلول سبتمبر 2017 10:59

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to update the locale via the `updateLocale` method.

```js
moment.updateLocale("en", { postformat: (string:string) => string });
```